# React Native Expo error unauthorized request

Tags: react-native, expo

I have been developing an application for quite some time and yesterday when I have run expo, i kept on getting spammed by this error that I am using extensions that intercept the Http request but I was using my iPhone to see the app which had no extension that could intercept it. Any help would be much appreciated

Error: Unauthorized request from http://y6-yyr.anonymous.alb-mobile.exp.direct. This may happen because of a conflicting browser extension to intercept HTTP requests. Please try again without browser extensions or using incognito mode.
at remoteDevtoolsSecurityHeadersMiddleware

**EDIT**

Found out that the problem occured from my Wifi, but any help to fix it would be more than great !

[Expo Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuNO1.png)

Comment: This is also happening to me because of my wifi. I'm on a train wifi that works for other things, specifically Amtrak, so I'm not sure why the wifi is causing this issue